# AngularJS update view with service/model changes using $q promises

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I'm trying to load data from a service and update the view using $q, but it's not working.  It works if I put the http call inside the controller, but I'd prefer it be part of the service.

Any help?  Also, is there a better way to do this instead of promises?

Demo and code below.

---------- [**Fiddle Demo Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/m3hZ9/) ----------

**View**

```
<div ng-init="getData()">
  <div ng-repeat="item in list">{{item.name}}</div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', 'dataservice', '$q', function ($scope, dataservice, $q) {

  $scope.list = dataservice.datalist;

  var loadData = function () {
    dataservice.fakeHttpGetData();
  };

  var setDataToScope = function () {
    $scope.list = dataservice.datalist;
  };

  $scope.getData = function () {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    defer.promise.then(setDataToScope());
    defer.resolve(loadData());
  };

}])
```

**Service**

```
.factory('dataservice', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {

  // view displays this list at load 
  this.datalist = [{'name': 'alpha'}, {'name': 'bravo'}];

  this.fakeHttpGetData = function () {
    $timeout(function () {

      // view should display this list after 2 seconds
      this.datalist = [{'name': 'charlie'}, {'name': 'delta'}, {'name': 'echo'}];
    },
    2000);
  };

  return this;
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for ngInit or $q. This is how you should do it.

You should also not expose `dataservice.list` to the controller. That should be private to `dataservice`, which will contain most of the logic to determine whether to send the controller the existing list or update the list and then send it.

```
angular.module('app', [])

        .controller('ctrl', ['$scope', 'dataservice', function ($scope, dataservice) {

            loadData();

            function loadData() {
                dataservice.fakeHttpGetData().then(function (result) {
                    $scope.list = result;
                });
            }
        }])

        .factory('dataservice', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {

            var datalist = [
                {
                    'name': 'alpha'
                },
                {
                    'name': 'bravo'
                }
            ];

            this.fakeHttpGetData = function () {

                return $timeout(function () {

                            // Logic here to determine what the list should be (what combination of new data and the existing list).

                            datalist =  [
                                {
                                    'name': 'charlie'
                                },
                                {
                                    'name': 'delta'
                                },
                                {
                                    'name': 'echo'
                                }
                            ];

                            return datalist;
                        },
                        2000);
            };

            return this;
        }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't use `ng-init` in this way. As per the docs:

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties
>   of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should
>   use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

Secondly, promises are the perfect thing to use in this case, but you don't need to touch `$q`, as `$http` calls return promises for you.

To do this properly, simply return the `$http` result from the service:

```
this.getDataFromService = function() {
    return $http(/* http call info */);
};
```

Then, inside you controller:

```
dataservice.getDataFromService().then(function(result){
    $scope.list = result.data;
});
```

Also here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RgwLR/

Bear in mind that `$q.when()` simply wraps the given value in a promise (mimicking the response from `$http` in your example).

Comment: IIRC, the result in the `.then` of the HTTP is the request itself, and you want `result.data`

Comment: Yes, but the fiddle is not making an HTTP request, is it :)?

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot that it adds a bunch of extras.